# How to map Form Parameter with Hibernate Entity Class in Spring-MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am new at Hibernate/JPA and I am trying to get form parameter with hibernate entity class. There was no problem with it until when I tried to get parameter with Entity class that has relationship with other class. For example;

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProduct(Model model, Product product) {
        databaseService.insert(product);
        return "redirect:/products";
    }
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private String price;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Category class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

The program cannot set 'category'. Because category is not type like int, string.. I am realize the problem. But I cannot find solution to mapping parameters with Entity class. Is there any way to solve this. Or should I use @RequestParam to get parameters one-by-one instead of mapping parameters with entity class.

**UPDATE**

I just change `category` to `category.id` in my .jsp page and it solved my problem. 
old code

```
<form>
...
    <select class="form-control" name="category">
    <c:if test="${not empty categoryList}">
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${categoryList}">
            <option value="${item.getId()}">${item.getName()}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
    </select>
</form>
```

new code

```
<form>
...
    <select class="form-control" name="category.id">
    <c:if test="${not empty categoryList}">
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${categoryList}">
            <option value="${item.getId()}">${item.getName()}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to add annotations on fields inside Category class as well. Can you post the content of Category chass here.

Comment: I updated post. You can see Category content.

Comment: In the post method you can retrieve any parameters from the model which is deserialized from them.

Comment: You dont have reverse mapping (One to Man7) from Category to the entity class. You may also need to add a inverse property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show us your form mapping,
Till then can could try with, change **path** in `<form:select>`/`<form:input>` tag to `category.id` and `category.name`

have a look at my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48356313/3425489)

I will suggest don't expose your **Entity** in the **View**, try to get form data in **DTO**, then convert to entity..

Comment: I think you are right. I am gonna use DTO. After some search, people suggest to use DTO to mapping form object. Even people strongly doesn't recommend to use entity class to mapping form parameter.

Comment: I redesigned my code. So I cannot try it now. But I will. And I cannot up voting because my reputation under 15.

Comment: Yes it is work. Thanks for answer. I tagged accepting answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is by creating a custom **Spring Converter**. So lets say you will be passing your entity's Id as a path variable, and your converter implementation would get that product object for you.

In your Controller you will need to do the following:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProduct(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Product product) {
        databaseService.insert(product);
        return "redirect:/products";
    }
```

Your Converter would look something like this:

```
    import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
    public class StringToProductConverter implements Converter<String, Product> {
    ...
    @Override
        public Product convert(String id) {
            Product product = databaseService.getProduct(id);
            ...
            return product;
        }
```

And **don't forget** to register your Converter either programmatically or by XML depending on your Spring version you're working on.